# Output tablename of two tables and other attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have two tables like this:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb77`.`supplier`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb77`.`supplier` (
  `sp_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sp_company` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sp_location` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sp_id`));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb77`.`customer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb77`.`customer` (
  `cu_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cu_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cu_title` VARCHAR(15) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `cu_location` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cu_id`);
```

how can I get the following output:

[image]

Ordered by name.

The tables have a different number of columns.

Comment: "The tables have a different number of columns."  The data that you provided shows the same number of columns.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html? There are several examples of sorting the result of a UNION on that page.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for the hint, I have changed it.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes but I have used TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE and alway get the different columns error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with `union all`:

```
select 'supplier' as tablename, sp_id as id,
       sp_company as name, sp_location as location
from supplier
union all
select 'customer', cu_id, cu_company, cu_location
from customer
order by 3;
```